# Vue custom filter does not work when defined globally

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So here is the jsFiddle example:

html:

```
<div id="demo">
  does not show $ sign in input as in second input - why? <br>
  <!-- the diff is only that filter is defined diferently -->    
  <input type="text" v-model="a | currencyDisplay">
  <span >model value: {{a }}</span>
</div>
```

Js:

```
Vue.filter('currencyDisplay', {
  currencyDisplay: {
    // model -> view
    // formats the value when updating the input element.
    read: function(val) {
      console.log('filter red');
      return '$'+val.toFixed(2)
    },
    // view -> model
    // formats the value when updating the data.
    write: function(val, oldVal) {
      console.log('filter write');

      var number = +val.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
      return isNaN(number) ? 0 : number
    }
  }
})

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    a: 5
  }
})
```

When I look in the source of the documentation example, they put code like this which works:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#two-way-filter-demo',
  data: {
    money: 123.45
  },
  filters: {
    currencyDisplay: {
      read: function(val) {
        return '$'+val.toFixed(2)
      },
      write: function(val, oldVal) {
        var number = +val.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
        return isNaN(number) ? 0 : number
      }
    }
  }
})
```

So the difference is the way how filter is defined. But it has to work both ways according to documentation. What is wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/975/

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `currencyDisplay` key from the global filter:

```
Vue.filter('currencyDisplay', {
  read: function (val) {
    return '$' + val.toFixed(2)
  },
  write: function (val, oldVal) {
    var number = +val.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
    return isNaN(number) ? 0 : number
  }
})
```